# Invoke POST request to google cloud function .net core library

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-functions, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use Google Cloud Functions on .Net Core 3.1 leveraging the library `Google.Cloud.Functions.v1`, and I am not able to invoke a post request. The lack of documentation and sample is quite frustrating by the way.

I am following [this code sample](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.Functions.V1/latest/api/Google.Cloud.Functions.V1.CloudFunctionsServiceClient.html#Google_Cloud_Functions_V1_CloudFunctionsServiceClient_CallFunctionAsync_Google_Cloud_Functions_V1_CallFunctionRequest_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_) where it shows how to call a function.

My scenario is a sample cloud function, that requires authentication, and expects data in the request body. The documentation above does have a `Data` attribute, however it is being ignored in the request.

My code:

```cs
CloudFunctionsServiceClient cloudFunctionsServiceClient = CloudFunctionsServiceClient.Create();
object data = new { message = "Testing post" };

CallFunctionRequest request = new CallFunctionRequest
{
    CloudFunctionName = CloudFunctionName.FromProjectLocationFunction("<proj>", "<region>", "<name>"), //I am hidding the values
    Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
};

try
{
    CallFunctionResponse response = await cloudFunctionsServiceClient.CallFunctionAsync(request);
    return response.Result;
}
```

This results in a `GET` request and using Fiddler I can tell that this `Data` attribute is not in the request.

How can I make a `POST` request to my function?

Comment: Have you tried checking here for a sample? https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet

Comment: Yes, they are the same as https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.Functions.V1/latest/api/Google.Cloud.Functions.V1.CloudFunctionsServiceClient.html#Google_Cloud_Functions_V1_CloudFunctionsServiceClient_CallFunctionAsync_Google_Cloud_Functions_V1_CallFunctionRequest_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_

Comment: Then you have the best documentation that exists.

Comment: @DaImTo could you let me know if the dotnet library doesnt support `POST` then?

Comment: I think what @DalmTo was trying to say is that, if you're not able to make a POST request using the Client Library's methods, then it is not currently supported by the maintainers. If that's the case, then the best option for you is to create your own request following the REST (or RPC) API from scratch.